# Simplify $\sum_{i=0}^{N/2}{N-i\choose i}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

EDIT: Really sorry to put you through the trouble. The expression I am looking for is actually the summation of these values. Not the product. My bad

I'm looking for a condensed form of $\sum_{i=0}^{N/2}{N-i\choose i}$.

E.g. for $n=6$, I want to reduce ${6\choose0}+{5\choose1}+{4\choose2}+{3\choose3}$ into a single NCR or something that can be computed easily. Is it possible?

Comment: What are C0*5, &c.?

Comment: Product of binomial coefficients $6\choose0$ $5\choose1$ $4\choose2$ $3\choose3$?

Comment: Yes. How to i efficiently computer this. N could be as large as 10^6

Comment: The exact value, or is an approximation enough? Try small values of $N$, perhaps something stands out.

Comment: I have tried to compute it on WolframAlpha but the expression I obtained is not simple at all!

Comment: See [OEIS A$073617$](http://oeis.org/A073617) and [OEIS A$203469$](http://oeis.org/A203469).

Comment: Does the sequence 1,1,2,3,5,8 ring a bell?

Comment: It is rude to change the question so radically. You should have left the original (perhaps with a comment that it was a mistake) for the (admittedly remote) possibility that someone *did* get a closed form or a decent asymptotic value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s well known that

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n-k}k=F_{n+1}\;,$$

the $n$-th Fibonacci number, where $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ for $n\ge 2$. This is easily proved by induction on $n$. The induction step is

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n+1-k}k&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\binom{n-k}k+\binom{n-k}{k-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n-k}k+\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n-k}{k-1}\\
&\overset{*}=F_{n-1}+\sum_{k\ge 1}\binom{n-k}{k-1}\\
&=F_{n-1}+\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n-1-k}k\\
&\overset{*}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\\
&=F_n\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the two starred steps are applications of the induction hypothesis.

Note that there’s no need to specify an upper limit on the summation: once $k$ exceeds $n-k$, the binomial coefficient is $0$ anyway.

Comment: Bang on. Thanks

Comment: @bholagabbar: You’re welcome.