# Proof verification: Number of minimal selfish set.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, solution-verification, contest-math, fibonacci-numbers

From the 1996 Putnam B1:

> Define a selfish set to be a set which has its own cardinality as an element.  A minimal selfish (m.s.) is a selfish set with no proper subset selfish.  How many subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ are m.s.?

My proof is below.  I appreciate comments on the accuracy of the proof, the method I use, and the writing.

Lemma: Let $s$ be a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and let $l$ be the least element in $s$.  $s$ is m.s. iff $l = |s|$.

Proof: If $l = |s|$, $s$ is clearly selfish.  Any proper subset $t$ of $s$ will have cardinality $k < l$, implying that $k$ is not a member of $s$ or $t$, and that $t$ is not selfish.  Hence, $s$ is m.s.

Conversely, if $l \neq |s|$, $s$ is not m.s.  For if $l > |s|$, $s$ is not even selfish.  And if $l < |s|$, there exists a subset $t$ of $s$ with cardinality $l$ and with $l$ a member, making $t$ selfish and hence $s$ not m.s.

Therefore, the number of m.s. subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ are precisely the number of subsets whose least element $l$ equals their cardinality.  These subsets can be constructed by:

1. Choosing any element as $l$
2. Choosing $l-1$ elements from the remaining $n-l$ elements greater than $l$.  There are ${n-l \choose l-1}$ ways to do this, defining ${n \choose r}$ as 1 if $r=0$ and as 0 if $r>n$.

Therefore, there are $\sum_{l=1}^{n} {n-l \choose l-1}$ m.s. subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but your final result can be improved:

$$\sum_{\ell=1}^n\binom{n-\ell}{\ell-1}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n-1-k}k\overset{(*)}=F_n\,,$$

the $n$-th Fibonacci number. (There is a proof of $(*)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387664/simplify-sum-i-0n-2n-i-choose-i/1387891#1387891).)

By the way, you don’t have to mention that $\binom{n}0=1$ and $\binom{n}r=0$ if $r>n$: those definitions are standard.